# Speech plug-in for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I'm Using Visual Studio 2008. At

http://gotspeech.net/elearning/

- Building Voice Workflows
- Create Voice Response Application

it says to

> open Visual Studio 2008, choose new
>   project c# and choose "speech"

but it doesn't appear ...

I installed the speech Server on an IIS and there Visual Studio is installed, too.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one - unless the 3rd party tool you are using installs one.  The easiest way to do speech with VS is to install the platform SDK which has several TTS examples in there.